# How to integrate the fadeIn fadeOut effect on the Angular routes

Tags: angular, angular-animations

In my Angular application I have implemented the functionality for the animation of the routes following the instructions at the following link: [Route transition animations](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations).

I would like to replace the slideIn animation defined in the "route-transition-animations.ts" file with an effect identical to the one inserted by navigating through the pages of the Angular site (**fadeIn-fadeOut** effect).

I have tried:

```
export const fadeAnimation =
trigger('routeAnimations', [
    transition('* => *', [
        query(':enter', [
                style({ opacity: 0 })
            ], { optional: true }
        ),
        group([
            query(':leave', [
                    animate(300, style({ opacity: 0 }))
                ],
                { optional: true }
            ),
            query(':enter', [
                    style({ opacity: 0 }),
                    animate(300, style({ opacity: 1 }))
                ],
                { optional: true }
            )
        ])
    ])
]);
```

With the following CSS:

```
ng-deep:: router-outlet~* {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone help me define the animation style?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5: fade animation during routing (CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805954/angular-5-fade-animation-during-routing-css)

Comment: @shhdharmen No, I have a bad effect: no transition and the views appear for a moment in the same router-outlet

Comment: Can you share the code of your animations?

Comment: @shhdharmen Sure, I have updated my question.

Comment: I mean it would be great if you could create stackblitz with everything.